# Jupyter matlab kernel disconnect after 5 min

Tags: matlab, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I install the matlab jupyter extension in order to use matlab in jupyter notebook/lab. But the problem is that when I run a cell more than 5 min, it will disconnect. errors are as following:

[image: errors]

When a cell has runtime less than that, everything is ok. I am using matlab R2021b. Python 3.8.16.
Information about some package might be related :

[image: list of packages]

I've tried to find settings in matlab but didn't find anything relate to that.
And for jupyter setting I don't find something about communicating with matlab.

Expect: matlab on jupyter run a cell more than 5 mins. First I need to know what problem is this. Is it from jupyter or from matlab? What should I do to let it work normally?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Open an issue on their github